# What are the differences between Python Playwright sync vs. async APIs?

Tags: python, async-await, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I've started learning [playwright-python](https://microsoft.github.io/playwright-python/) and the package `playwright` has the two submodules `async_api` and `sync_api`. However I could not find any deeper description or discussion on their respective benefits and drawbacks. From their names I assume that the synchronous API calls are blocking and the asynchronous ones run in the background?

Are they different in their capabilities, i.e. are there scenarios in which the `sync_api` cannot accomplish something you can do using the `async_api` (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sync_api` is simply a wrapper around the `asyncio_api` that abstracts asyncio usage away from you. As such, the capabilities are largely the same, but the `async_api` *may* afford some more flexibility in complex scenarios.

I would suggest using async in case you need the flexibility in the future, or sync for ease of use.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [Playwright doc](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/library), the `async_api` module should be used if your Python project uses the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module.

`asyncio` stands for Asynchronous I/O.

I have never used it, but my understanding is that it is a Python library that allows you to do concurrent I/O operations, so they can be executed asynchronous, meaning that each I/O operation is non-blocking. If an I/O operations takes too long, Python continues the execution of the next lines of code without waiting the completion of the previous I/O operation(s).

If you don't use the `asyncio` module in your Python project, there is no need to use `async_api` and you can use `sync_api` instead.